# I want to search for values in binary search tree using iteration

Tags: java, search, iteration, binary-search-tree

Hello I wrote this method to search for values in my binary search tree but it is always returning false whether the value is found in my bst or not. can someone please tell me what's my mistake and how I can fix it.

```
    public boolean search(int key) {
    BinaryTreeNode subRoot = null;
          
        while (subRoot != null)  
        {  
             
            if (key > subRoot.getData()) {
                root = subRoot.getRight();  
            }
             
            else if (key < subRoot.getData())  
                root = subRoot.getLeft();  
            else
                System.out.println("Searching for " + key + ": found");
                return true; 
        }  
        System.out.println("Searching for " + key + ": NOT found");
        return false;  
    
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: As well as the problem mentioned in Cezar Todirisca's answer, you are assigning values to `root`, but checking `subRoot`.  It seems to me that you should be checking the variable you've just assigned - that is, use `subRoot` everywhere you've used `root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having more input this is everything I can do.
You forgot to assign subRoot to root at the beginning.
You here assigning values to your root in the loop this would lead to loss of data and most likely a infinite-loop.
Plus your else statement had no brakets, so it would always return true if you entered the loop.

```
public boolean search(int key) {
BinaryTreeNode subRoot = root;
      
    while (subRoot != null)  
    {  
         
        if (key > subRoot.getData()) 
            subRoot = subRoot.getRight();             
        else if (key < subRoot.getData())  
            subRoot = subRoot.getLeft();  
        else{
            System.out.println("Searching for " + key + ": found");
            return true;
        } 
    }  
    System.out.println("Searching for " + key + ": NOT found");
    return false;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialize subRoot with null before the while loop, so when you check the condition it will always be false, therefore going to the end of the function

Comment: That is *a* problem, but not the only problem.

Comment: Indeed. The code will go into an infinite loop if the item searched for is not found in the root. There are us also an incorrect indenting issue. And the tree will have lost data after a search, but but it went into an infinite loop so you won't notice that problem.

Comment: How can i fix this?